# Ckeditor 5 - Couldn't upload file: logo.jpg / codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor, codeigniter-4, ckeditor5

I am trying to implement ckeditor5 and SimpleUploadAdapter.  I get an error, `Couldn't upload file: logo.jpg`

```
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#post_body' ), {
  
    simpleUpload: {
        // The URL that the images are uploaded to.
        uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/upload/posts/',

        // Enable the XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property.
        withCredentials: true,

        // Headers sent along with the XMLHttpRequest to the upload server.
        headers: {
             
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': +CKeditorToken_name,
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' +CKeditorToken_hash,
        }
    }
} )
.catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
} );
```

I am a bit confused as to what `X-CSRF-TOKEN` and `Authorization` require.  I am passing the value of [csrf_token()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=csrf_token#csrf_token) which is the name of the current CSRF token and [csrf_hash()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=csrf_token#csrf_hash) which is the current value of the CSRF hash.  Is that what is needed here?

Also, for the upload url, which is correct;

```
uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/upload/posts/
```

or
uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/upload/posts

In the console, the following error is shown:

```
simpleuploadadapter.js:224          POST https://example.com/upload/posts/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Any pointer or guidance much appreciated.

I have double and triple checked directory permissions and path and all are ok.

Comment: Please show us the route mapping in your `app/Config/Routes.php` file corresponding to the route `upload/posts`.

Comment: I really don't understand simpleuploadadapter implementation.  Do I need to write a method for uploading?  How about the X-CSRF-TOKEN and Authorization?  Thank you.